# Assigning int *[10] from type void* when using shmat

Tags: c, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I'm looking at some example code and trying to figure this out but am stuck. I'm just trying to create a buffer of 10 ints and have my shared memory pointers point to that. Can someone help me understand what this code is actually doing and where I went wrong?

```
int shmem_id;       /* shared memory identifier */
int *shmem_ptr[BUFSIZE];     /* pointer to shared segment */
key_t key = 4455;         /* a key... */
int size = 2048;        /* 2k memory */
int flag = 1023;        /* permissions */
char keystr[10];
sprintf (keystr, "%d", key);
shmem_id = shmget (key, size, flag);    /* create a shared memory segment */
shmem_ptr = shmat (shmem_id, (void *) NULL, 1023);
```

In reality I want it to a buffer of 10 struct items.

```
typedef struct widget{
   char color[10];
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your declaration:

```
int *shmem_ptr[BUFSIZE];
```

declares `shmem_ptr` to be an array of pointers to integers. You just want a pointer to integers, so it should be:

```
int *shmem_ptr;
```

If the memory points to `widget` structures, you can do:

```
typedef struct widget {
    char color[10];
} widget;

widget *shmem_ptr;
```

You don't need to declare the length when declaring a pointer. The length is specified when the shared memory block is created, not in the program that attaches to it.

Comment: I see that now. But here for example, I should be declaring 10 structures and am trying to get the shared memory pointer to point to it.
`code`
struct widget shmem[BUFSIZE];
shmem = shmat (shmem_id, (void *) NULL, 1023);
`code`
Should I put shmem in place of void null in the shmat call? Or maybe I'm thinking of this backwards?